# Remove spaces within brackets except for text in quotation marks

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regex which can remove spaces when they are between matching brackets, i.e. `(` and `)`, *except* when there are spaces inside quotation marks ( `'` or `"`) *inside* the brackets.

I currently have the regex `\s+(?=[^(]*\))`, which removes all spaces found between brackets. So also when there are spaces in quotation marks.

```
// My input
do something with(in = 1, text='some text with spaces' , text2="also has spaces")

// My current output
do something with(in=1,text='sometextwithspaces',text2="alsohasspaces")

// My desired output
do something with(in=1,text='some text with spaces',text2="also has spaces")
```

Furthermore:

- Quotation marks can only be found inside the brackets
- There can be `"` in `'` `'` text: `text='text with " inside'`, without the `\` escape character.
- There can be `'` in `"` `"` text: `text="text with ' inside"`, without the `\` escape character.
- There is **no** escape character before the quotation mark in the string: `text='This is \" not there'`

I know there are quite some questions about regex patterns, but I couldn't find one which did the trick. Among the many things that I've tried were look forwards to only find things in between `(` until `'` or `"` with `\s+(?=[^("]*[\)"])`, but that still finds the spaces in between `"` and `"`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I use the pattern in C#.

Comment: Do you have case of `text='some put \" in the text with \' to *** with my code'` ? (regex are *very bad* choice for nested constructs/counting, write simple parser instead)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, see updated question.

Comment: Do you have access to the code? What code are you using now?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I have access to the code. I'm currently using the first regex in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to the regular expression you used :

```regex
# match a space or more 
# if the fol
(?<!['"][^,]*)\s+(?=[^(]*\))|\s+(?![^,]*['"])(?=[^(]*\))
```

the regular expression is split into two parts the regular expression will match either one of them:

1. the first part `(?<!['"][^,]*)\s+(?=[^(]*\))` matches as much white space as possible `\s+` that's not preceded by a quote `'"` (`(?<!['"][^,]*)`) and if only it's followed by a closing parenthesis. `(?=[^(]*\))`
2. the second part `\s+(?![^,]*['"])(?=[^(]*\))` matches as much white space as possible `\s+` that's not succeeded by a quote  `(?![^,]*['"])` and only if it's followed by a closing parenthesis `(?=[^(]*\))`.

[you can test it here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%27%22%5d%5b%5e%2c%5d*%29%5cs%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%28%5d*%5c%29%29%7c%5cs%2b%28%3f!%5b%5e%2c%5d*%5b%27%22%5d%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%28%5d*%5c%29%29&i=do+something+with%28.+++++++in+%3d+1%2c++%27some+%5c%27+text+with+spaces%5c%22%27++++%2c+text2+%0d%0a+%3d+++%22also+has+spaces%22+%29)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution made it into the project with attribution https://github.com/Roald87/TcBlack/commit/1f868cebfd0e3f795e8015db0185b5a26c1b295c!

Comment: counter example: `counter example ("(" 123  456  ")") 789`; expected: spaces within parenthesis matched, actual: they ae not

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you have *two* kind of quotations, `"` and `'` you have to deal with *quotation of quotation*:

```
  abc"def pqr' ijk" "klm ' xyz"
```

Note that *both* apostrophes are enquoted and that's why don't work. Same with *brackets*. I doubt if a
simple regular expression can help out here, but Finite State Machine can:

```
private static string RemoveSpaces(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  bool inQuotation = false;
  bool inApostroph = false;
  int bracketCount = 0;
  int escapeCount = 0;
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  foreach (char c in value) {
    if (inQuotation) {
      result.Append(c);
      inQuotation = c != '"' || (escapeCount % 2 != 0);
    }
    else if (inApostroph) {
      result.Append(c);
      inApostroph = c != '\'' || (escapeCount % 2 != 0);
    }
    else {
      if (c != ' ' || bracketCount <= 0)
        result.Append(c);

      if (c == '(')
        bracketCount += 1;
      else if (bracketCount == ')')
        bracketCount -= 1;

      inQuotation = c == '"' && (escapeCount % 2 == 0);
      inApostroph = c == '\'' && (escapeCount % 2 == 0);
    }

    escapeCount = c == '\\' ? escapeCount + 1 : 0;
  }
  return result.ToString();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string test =
  @"do something with(in = 1, text='some text with spaces' , text2=""also has spaces"")";

Console.WriteLine(RemoveSpaces(test));
```

**Outcome:**

```
do something with(in=1,text='some text with spaces',text2="also has spaces")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just learned about regex and found it quite amazing what it can do. In my enthusiasm I may have overused it. So, today I learned that there are also limits to what it can do.

Comment: @Roald: *parsing* (and you parse some kind of source code) is not a strong side of regular expressions; please note, that if you want to add some more states, e.g. introduce comments `/* ... */` you can easily do it in case of FSM